# How to find child of nested elements using Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the information within `<span>` tags within `<p>` tags within the `<div>` tag using Python and BeautifulSoup. I am looking for the information within the 'Data that I want to read' `<span>`.

```
<body>
    <div id='output'>
        <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word">CONNECTED</p>
        <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word">SENT</p>
        <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word">
            <span style="color: blue">
                Data that I want to read
            <span/>
        </p>
    <div/>
<body/>
```

I have the following, which finds the text within the `<div>` tags and nothing else.

```
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

websiteData = soup.find_all("div")

for someData in websiteData:
    childElement = someData.findChildren("p", recursive=True)
    for child in childElement:
        childElementofChildElement = child.findChildren("span", recursive=True)
        for child in childElementofChildElement:
            print(child)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector for the task:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''\
<body>
    <div id='output'>
        <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word">CONNECTED</p>
        <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word">SENT</p>
        <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word">
            <span style="color: blue">
                Data that I want to read
            </span>
        </p>
    <div/>
<body/>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for t in soup.select('div#output p span'):
    print(t.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Data that I want to read
```

---

CSS selector `div#output p span` means select all `<span>` tags that are under `<p>` tag and the `<p>` tag should be under `<div>` tag with `id="output"`.